# structr: badMessage: 400 Unknown Version for HttpChannelOverHttp

Tags: neo4j, jetty, structr

here the related post on google:

[badMessage: 400 Unknown Version for HttpChannelOverHttp](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/structr/fRG9SEP-fD4)

I got an exception with status code 400 (unknown version) from `httpParser`,
but i don't understand what happened and how i can fix the problem.
What is the Reason for this Exception? 
The Code says: `version == null`

here is the code:

```java
String version=takeString();
_version=HttpVersion.CACHE.get(version);
if (_version==null)
  throw new BadMessage(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST_400,"Unknown Version");
setState(State.SPACE1);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i added more details in the post

Comment: I've replied to the post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/structr/fRG9SEP-fD4.

Answer (score 23):

this message usually occurs if you have a whitespace (or other characters which have to be URL-encoded properly) in the URL, like f.e.

```
curl "http://0.0.0.0:8082/structr/rest/users?name=A B"
```

Correct:

```
curl "http://0.0.0.0:8082/structr/rest/users?name=A%20B"
```

Hope that helps,
Axel